# How to create a dynamic array of linked list nodes in c?

Tags: c

Basically, array should be initialized on user input. If `input = 3`, that means this array can store one linked list in index `0,1,2` respectively (so total 3 lists)

```
int input = 3;
list* array[n]//not allowed as n is not constant, also not in heap so can't pass it across functions
list* array[] = (list*) malloc(sizeof(list)*input)//compiler error
```

Preparing for interviews...so you can say home-work!

Comment: The question and code contradicts each other; do you want to dynamically allocate a set of lists or a set of list nodes?

Comment: array of linked list....so array[0] has listA and array[1] points to listB. in other words, instead of an array of array, i want array of linked list. But size of array has to be decided on user's input

Answer (score 1):

An array of linked lists could be either an array of head nodes (assuming a standard linked list implementation) or an array of pointers to lists. In either case, the problem you seem to be facing is how to dynamically allocate an array.

The generic syntax for dynamically allocating an array on the heap is

```
type * array = calloc(number_of_elements, sizeof(type))
```

Correcting the compilation error in your code would thus be

```
int input = 3;
list ** array = calloc(input, sizeof(list*));
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

It should be `list* array = malloc(sizeof(list) * input)`, `malloc` returns base address of the newly allocated memory location. You can use this as the array i.e. you can access `array[0]..array[input - 1]`.

Comment: But doesn't it mean that array is actually just a linked list with this much memory allocated? how would i access it index wise?

Answer (score 0):

A (single) linked list is often a structure with a pointer to the next structure. This pattern makes it easy to add, delete and insert things from that list and still keeps the whole data usage flexible and governed in run-time.

a linked list in your situation will look like this

```
struct List
{
 // contents of the list
 List* Pointer_to_next_list;
};
```

Then you can add functions for keeping track of each list. I suggest reading [Wikipedia::Linked List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) for how this works.